# How do I install SSH2 for PHP 5.5 on Centos 6.4 64 bit?

Tags: php, magento, ssh, cron, centos

I was installing SSH2 extenion for PHP 5.5, to fulfill magento's requirement (Ability to run scheduled jobs (crontab) with PHP 5 ). When I ran "pecl install -f ssh2" it gave me following error:

> PHP Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 262144 bytes exhausted (tried
>   to allocate 3200 bytes) in /usr/share/pear/pearcmd.php on line 66

Should I change the value of pearcmd.php?

Comment: Try increasing the limit in your `php.ini` file, as `memory_limit = 64M`. Does that help?

Comment: I have already made it 256MB, because magento demands at least 256MB and 512MB is recommended. However my php.ini states two lines above to memory_limit value, "; Maximum amount of memory a script may consume (128MB)", what is this?

Comment: The default value in some versions of php.ini.
Note that PHP has several possible configurations, one for Apache with mod_php, and one for command line execution. Make sure you edit the right one - check with `php -i` on the command line which file is being used.

Comment: Double check that memory limit again, because based on the posted message you have the memory limit set to 256K, not 256M.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to modify your php.ini.

You may set the memory limit for the current command using `-d`. See: `pecl help options`

```
pecl -d memory_limit=500M install -f ssh2
```

You may install this module also using yum from [epel](http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/EPEL) repo:

```
rpm -Uvh http://download.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/6/i386/epel-release-6-8.noarch.rpm
yum install php-pecl-ssh2
```